# Arbitrary-length currying

Tags: code-golf, functional-programming, recursion

Write a function, `f`, that takes in a positive integer and returns a function.

The new function returned should be identical to `f`. However, when the "termination call" happens, `f` should instead return the sum of all integers passed.

For example, `g=f(4)` (if `f` is the first function) should set `g` to another function. `h=g(3)` will do the same. However, when you call `h` with no arguments (see below for details), it should output 7, as that is the sum of the previous function arguments.   Put another way, `f(3)(4)() == 7`.

Do note this is not the same as `f(3,4)()`.

"Termination call" is one of the following options (your choice):

- call w/o arguments
- null as argument
- any non-positive value

Arbitrary amount of function calls should be supported, there is no predefined limit.

It's guaranteed that total sum will not be bigger than 1'000.

We can assume that there is at least one call is made prior to "termination call".

Your code should not use static, per-program variables, so it should be possible to run the experiment multiple times in the same runtime and observe exactly the same behavior.

Examples:

```
f(1)() == 1
f(4)(2)(7)() == 13
f(4)(2)(7)(5)(2)() == 20
```

Comment: Can we require a specific non-positive value as the terminator?

Comment: @Tutleman, not sure what it would lead to, let's say any non-positive should be OK to terminate the chain if this option is choosen

Comment: I don't understand what is being asked here. Can you ellaborate or clarify? What does the notation `f(4)(2)(7)()` mean?

Comment: @LuisMendo It generally means that `f(4)` returns a new function. If that new function is called without arguments, it returns `4`, but if it's called with another argument then it will *again* return a new function with the same semantics but with the new argument added to the `4` and so on.

Comment: @LuisMendo, it means 4 function calls, arguments on first 3 should be summed, because the forth call is "terminating"

Comment: @MartinEnder Thanks. So does the code need to return a function, or is that just one possible approach? Can it be a function with a "persistent" variable, such that _the same_ function is called several times? This question is more for Eugene I guess

Comment: @LuisMendo It's indeed up to Eugene, but I think that allowing repeated calls would significantly take away from the challenge, because the interesting part isn't to make a stateful function but to make a higher-order function.

Comment: @MartinEnder That makes a lot of sense. Eugene, if that's the intent, please change the wording of the challenge. _Write a function that can be infinitely called_ doesn't suggest at all that the function shoud return a function

Comment: Can we assume that there will only be one instance of the call chain at a time? E.g. No `q = f(2)(3); b = f(1)(2)(3); q(); b()`?

Comment: Are functors allowed?

Comment: Apologies, I am not sure I understand. I have a 'plus over' function in k `+/` ---- so `+/[1 2 3]` returns 6, is this incorrect? Do the arguments need to be (1)(2)(3)() - with parentheses AND a null terminator? What is the significance of the null terminator? If it isn't present should the function do nothing??

Comment: @EugeneD.Gubenkov Let me know when you clarify the above (whether the function should return a function or simply have memory across calls), so that I can remove my downvote

Comment: @Chromozorz the significance is currying and higher-order functions. I think a better title would be "Arbitrary-length Currying".

Comment: @LuisMendo, Please check out the updated description -- should be more precise now.

Comment: `Arbitrary amount of function calls should be supported` I believe some environment won't able to handle more than 1000 recursive call. It will simply throw `StackOverflow` error.

Comment: @ThariqNugrohotomo, let's go with 1000 as maximum sum, it is not critical to the spirit of the challenge

Comment: Having just recently picked up Haskell, I'm interested in whether this is possible in Haskell. The strong type system makes me think it might not be.

Comment: I have some questions here. We can't use static storage so this function obviously needs some dynamically allocated buffer space. Does `f()` itself need to take care of that? Can `f()` take an additional parameter to a pre-allocated buffer? What about stack allocation? That has to be done (and eventually cleaned up) by the caller.

Comment: @CAD97 - I believe it is, although I don't have time to work on it right now.  The trick is that you can thread the expected output type of each function invocation backwards through in order to selected a typeclass instance at that invocation.  So just like `read "123"` can return either `Int` or `Float` depending on what the code calling it expects, `f` can have the type either `VariadicFunction v => Int -> v` or `() -> Int` depending on what's expected of it... It wouldn't be a short solution, but interestingly it may well be the only statically typed one on the list.

Comment: it should be `f(4)(3)()`, or the definitions should be flipped.

Comment: Does "any non-positive value" mean that we can e.g. specify 0 as the termination value and negative values as unsupported, or does it mean that, if we choose that option, the code must treat *all* non-positive inputs as termination values?

Comment: @CAD97 I haven't really learned Haskell yet, but I know that functions are curried by default. Does it have any varargs functionality? I found [this](https://wiki.haskell.org/Varargs).

Comment: Tangentially [related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43783517).

Comment: Would a builder pattern be ok, i.e `NewSum().Add(3).Add(4).Finish()`?

Answer (score 53):

### JavaScript (ES6), 18 bytes

```
f=n=>m=>m?f(m+n):n
```

Pass a falsy value to retrieve the sum. Zeros could be allowed for a cost of 2 bytes.

[Try it online](https://tio.run/nexus/javascript-babel-node#@59mm2drlwtE9mkaudp5mlZ5/5Pz84rzc1L1cvLTNRTSNAw1NYw0NYw1NXRNNDU0FTT/AwA)

**Ungolfed:**

```
f = function(n) {
    return function(m) {
        if (m) {
            return f(m+n);
        } else {
            return n;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Brilliant submission!

Answer (score 22):

### [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/) (GHC), 118 bytes

This is 98 bytes for the code and 20 bytes for the GHC compiler flag `-XFlexibleInstances`, which enables a type system extension.

```hs
class F a where f::Int->a
instance F(()->Int)where f n()=n
instance F a=>F(Int->a)where f=(f.).(+)
```

This defines a "function" `f`, which can be called with an arbitrary number of integers followed by the unit `()`, after which it returns an integer.
Type annotations are required.
[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/haskell#TY3LCsIwFET3fsVAN/ci6UJxE0igC1MK4s4PiCXBQL1IU1AQv72@Irg6w3CGuasKu2bfHpp2CzeEWzoOoZM8eelDRqUecz/4nOHgcT2FMSBq3cmkrF@k4sERsbKvlosCITbyJ8Ab6@i7@0mGYs01LXk@@yQwuIxJJlCk9eeCaVO4KmRojXeanw)

### Explanation

Forcing Haskell's strict type system to allow this requires some magic, namely, enabling the GHC extension for flexible typeclass instances.
How this works is that `f` is a parametrically polymorphic function restricted by a type class constraint: its type is `F a => Int -> a`.
This means that `f` takes an integer and returns a value of type `a`, for any type `a` that belongs to the typeclass `F`.
`F` is just the name of the typeclass that provides the function `f`; it's declared on the first line.

The next two lines are two instances of `F` for different types `a`.
The second line states that the type of functions from `()` to integers belongs to `F` (where `()` is the unit type whose only member is the value `()`), and the implementation is `f n () = n`; the function returns its first argument.
The last line states that if `a` belongs to `F`, then so does the type of functions from integers to `a`: from a function `f :: Int -> a` we can generate another function `f :: Int -> Int -> a`.
The implementation is `f m n = f (m+n)` (the code uses combinators to make it shorter), where the `f` on the left is the new one, and the `f` on the right is the old one.
This essentially gives `f` a new integer argument, which is added to the next one.
Multiple arguments are summed together like this:

```hs
  f  a1   a2   a3   a4   a5  ()
= f (a1 + a2)  a3   a4   a5  ()
= f (a1 + a2 + a3)  a4   a5  ()
= f (a1 + a2 + a3 + a4)  a5  ()
= f (a1 + a2 + a3 + a4 + a5) ()
=    a1 + a2 + a3 + a4 + a5
```

The `f` on each line has a different type.

Haskell functions are curried automatically, so if you give `f` only integers, you get a function.

Comment: Maybe I'm nitpicking, but it's not quite what the challenge asks for. You're defining two(!) functions, both called `f`, not a single function that does the job. However, this is as close as you can get in Haskell. I don't think it's possible to solve the task with a single function because of the strict type system.

Comment: @nimi This defines not two functions called `f`, but infinitely many functions called `f`. (One for each possible number of arguments.) These functions (from this infinite family) have two sorts of definitions, one sort when the number of arguments is zero, and another when it is not.

Comment: @ShreevatsaR: I see two definitions, `f n()=n` and `f=(f.).(+)`, so I'd call it defining two functions.

Comment: @nimi There are two definitions, but not two functions. The number of definitions need not be the number of functions. For example, you can define the factorial function with the two definitions `g 0 = 1` and `g n = g (n-1) * n`, where there are two definitions but just one function. Here we have two definitions but infinitely many functions. (Each of a different type.)

Comment: @ShreevatsaR: of course your example of the factorial function is just a single function. The two definitions in the code above are two individual definitions, because they are in different `where` contexts. Both `f` are of type `Int -> a`, so why shouldn't they be functions?

Comment: @nimi The first line says that, for a type `a` to belong to type class `F`, there must exist a function named `f` of type `Int -> a`. The next two lines declare that some types `a` belong to class `F`: namely types `()->Int`, `Int->(()->Int)`, `Int->(Int->(()->Int))` and so on. For each of these types (call them a1, a2, ...), the "justification" that the type belongs to class `F` is given by defining corresponding (different) functions `f`, which are of types `Int->a1`, `Int->a2`, and so on. We could add more definitions for new types. (E.g. we could add `instance F Char where f n = 'z'`.)

Comment: @nimi BTW in `ghci` load the above and try `:t f`— it will say `f :: F a => Int -> a` (meaning that if `a` is an instance of class `f`, then `f` is a function `Int -> a`). So we could consider this as either one function or infinitely many, but although it has two sorts of definitions (just like the factorial function) I don't see any good basis for considering it to be two functions.

Comment: Bending the rules a bit you could declare an instance for `Int` instead of `()->Int` and claim that you "need" to use use `0` as a final argument, even though it isn't required, [this](https://tio.run/##fc/BCsIwDAbg@54ixxaZiOKl0F0Gwt5g11pTV4xFloF9@tWKHaiH5RLI9yeQwfANiVKyZJihhQjPAUcEp1QXprqJlQ88mWAxY54srP3lW6JuWvFZkCWRZ24r4kamu/EBNDxGn/dFFnEApd7XZAX/JY4rtl@x3WKlw29Gptk6MldOdX8ijP5M2JUH@AU "Haskell – Try It Online") would save you 7 bytes. Using `()` is nicer, but then again this is codegolf :)

Answer (score 17):

## Python 2, <s>42</s> <s>41</s> 36 bytes

This solution will never have an overflow, since Python supports arbitrary-precision integers. Zero is the "special value".

```python
f=lambda n:lambda m:m and f(m+n)or n
```

[**Try it online**](https://tio.run/nexus/python2#@59mm5OYm5SSqJBnBWXkWuUqJOalKKRp5GrnaeYXKeT9LyjKzCsBChhqahgZaWrommpqGBoAsYmmhoHmfwA)

**Ungolfed:**

```python
def f(n):
    def g(m=''):
        return f(m+n)if m<''else n
    return g
```

Answer (score 14):

### Mathematica, 25 bytes

```
f[x_]@y_=f[x+y]
f[x_][]=x
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/mathics#@58WXREf61AZbwtkaFfGcoH50bG2Ff8DijLzShQcFNKijWOjTWKjDYEIyIr9DwA) (Using Mathics.)

It's possible to do three bytes less by porting the JavaScript answer, but I wanted to present a more idiomatic Mathematica solution. The `@` is just a bit of syntactic sugar, which makes the solution equivalent to:

```
f[x_][y_]=f[x+y]
f[x_][]=x
```

So yeah the idea is that in Mathematica you can't just define a function `f[x_]` but you can directly attach a value to a more complicated expression containing `f`, e.g. `f[x_]` being passed another argument. By setting up two definitions for this, we can get the desired behaviour:

- The first definition collapses one `f[x][y]` call into `f[x+y]`, thereby consuming one "call" and adding up the arguments inside. This rule applies until we're left with `f[sum][]`.
- The second definition unpacks this final case by defining the entire thing to evaluate to `sum`.

Comment: <3 symbolic programming

Answer (score 14):

## C, <s>62</s> 58 bytes, borderline competing

Saved 4 bytes thanks to Kevin! (Still not removing typedef because it's something needed in order to be called.)

```c
typedef(*(*B)(_))(_);q;f(x,o,_){x=x?(q+=x,f):(x=q,q=0,x);}
```

The function to call is `f`; you stop calling it and get the result by calling it with a non-positive number like `0`. **[Try a test harness online!](https://tio.run/nexus/c-gcc#lZDRaoNAEEXf/YohpTCr0qgJFNxsJX5HQUp1qdhqtrWwJeTb7YzZBDS@ZFBw5u49c9fhoW7fP3/LCnY/fVl3Tx8v3noN/d@hKiuN/l5gIaRrYY9@Pg6MzH2NTViIowlUs4uzKG1kM35hoUxoVERiirnQ8nQPsWNmp4w0DmsCBpuMUWlHsCvJWZ1doz2brbIZUiobagpgXRgryPr1Vrcojh5QHb7rtte40pjEAumJBCh4LF/bVYi0jN9RY5FVISe@JIYAYhjr4oPzcHZSYxxFArcJkTab58kmPueBK155bRYHl6FGICZQrhuZa5vcjKecBR9H85YdnHhsZhfjCAEt4zuTe/orZiJZT8PwDw)**

So, as far as I can tell, the only way to "curry" functions that have multiple return types is to do one of the following:

1. Cast the result to a function to tell the compiler you wish to call the result again;
2. or create a `union`/`struct` type that has an `int` and function/self-referential subtypes.

I tried doing (2), but it seemed a bit against the spirit of the question and, quite frankly, nigh undoable. Thus, in keeping with the spirit of the challenge, I have opted for option (1). This requires casting each returned function into a function, that it may be used.

This "currying" syntax looks a bit odd, but is quite similar. To emulate `f(21)(1)`, one would have to write `((B)((B)f(21))(1))(0)`. I defined the `B` type to be a function that takes an integer and returns a pointer to a function that takes an integer. Expanded, this looks like:

```c
   ( (B)( (B) f(21) )(1) )(0)
//            f(21)            - call f with 21
//        (B)                  - cast to B, a function pointer
//      (           )(1)       - call with 1
//   (B)                       - cast to a function pointer
// (                     )(0)  - call with 0
```

Comment: If you say it terminates on 0 only, you're going to require the casting (which you do in C because C can't properly define a function that returns itself), and you leave clearing the global between runs to the caller (which I think is perfectly reasonable), you can simplify the entire thing to `q;f(x){return x?(q+=x,f):q;}`.

Comment: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/c-gcc#bVB/C4JADP3/PsUwgl1KqAVBZkGfI4hIjw7qUlMwos9um2nkj3H7Y@/tve1WTbQ5X4sohs0jj/R9ftmKNFBYylcW50VmoNxhaoelo@Q6Dd5C5M8kjmKFM5ztJR4lZyDE7aQNypcAiiTTJldoKfQ9ifRcCSFMo4OxHERSUdYck8ySwb/O98AGD@podfAFm86UcDfoDfNcV@LSJ9PFYtUZyn0CmuDpv2IUaEGFQJ5AKw5ojqU/gLs@IzpeTYwreOO66F2DV7BpGH@f1N2r9EiSvqvqAw "C (gcc) – TIO Nexus")

Comment: @Kevin yet, as per site rules, a function must be reusable. If I didn't zero `q` after each run, then the function would no longer be useable

Comment: Maybe function pointers? You'd have to de reference every time but might be worth checking out

Comment: Shame. Still, you can get rid of the typedef and simplify to `q;f(x,o){return x?(q+=x,f):(x=q,q=0,x);}` ([Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/c-gcc#lVDRaoNAEHz3K5aUwp5K45lAwYuV@B0FKdWjYqs5a8AS8u1292JCNb508cCd2ZnZu@GhrN8/j3kBu@8uL5unjxdnvYbu51DkhUZ3LzATamxhj25qAaNSV2PlZ@JkvLjaySSIKlXZP8xi45s4IDLCVGh1/o9jw55NbJQZbY3HxiZhq6ghM6M09pe5tuiObQ19grRF72sK7MfwXtDoLXRMsUnO11tZozg5QHVoy7rTuNIYSoH0BQJieMxf65WPFMnHckwyS/q/ulCCBxJsXXVwAWeTGmUQCNyG5LTZPE@SeM6BsTjy1iwCV1AjkCfQXnc01za8g6c@CzpezVlW8Ma2mV2MV/AojO9M6ulTzEiSnofhFw "C (gcc) – TIO Nexus"))

Comment: @Kevin That's fantastic!

Comment: @ConorO'Brien I just [implemented](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/165391) your union approach. It's longer than this one, but it's not far off.

Comment: This solution seems to work fine when the function signature of f is [reduced to just `f(x)`](https://tio.run/##lVDbaoNAEH33K4aUwqzaRk2g4MZK/I6CFHVbsdVsa8EifrudsZuAxpcMCs45ey5r9vCWZeNdWWcfP3kBh@82L5vH92dru4X291TkhUL7KDAV0qxwRDuZAC0TW2HlpqLXTlQd/NgLK1lNX5hG2tWRR2SIiVByuMWxYc8m0lIbW@2wsY7ZKmzkMF6cjNTIFXai76IuRmrUuYrCO1OkEyT7fC1rFL0FNKevsm4VbhQGvkB6PAER3Ocv9cZFCuJ34phkVsiZLvDBAR@mOevgH1ycVOh7nsB9QE673dMsic9ZYIYjL8sqcAYVAnkC9bqiefbBFTz3WdFxNWtdwY2nZXExruBQGN@Z1PNfsSBJOox/)

Answer (score 8):

## C++, 72 bytes

```
#define O(P)operator()(P){return{P+a};}int
struct F{F O(int(m))O()a;}f;
```

This defines a type `F` which acts as the requested function, and a variable `f` of that type to invoke. It's valid as of C++11 and works with online versions of GCC, clang, icc and VC++.

Usage:

```
int main() {
  return f(1)(2)(3)(); // returns 6
}
```

Explanation:

After preprocessing and reformatting, it looks like:

```
struct F {
  F operator()(int(m)) { return{int(m)+a}; }
  int operator()() { return {+a}; }
  int a;
} f;
```

This would normally be written:

```
struct F {
  F operator()(int m) { return {m+a}; }
  int operator()() { return a; }
  int a;
} f;
```

`return a;` and `return {+a};` do the same thing, as unary `+` doesn't change the value, and redundant braces around the return value are allowed. `int m` and `int(m)` do the same thing, as redundant parentheses around a variable name are allowed, including function parameters. `return {m+a};` and `return {int(m)+a};` do the same thing, as a cast of `m` from `int` to `int` does not change its value. These changes get the two `operator()` overloads closer in syntax, allowing a single macro definition to be invoked twice. Picking the right order for the three members allows the first word of the next line (`int`) to be included in the macro definition as well.

Comment: Beautiful. And not just the golfed solution...overloading `operator()` to make this work was especially cool.

Answer (score 7):

## Ruby, 23 bytes

```rb
f=->n{->m{m ?f[n+m]:n}}
```

Usage:

```rb
f[1][2][3][nil]
=> 6
```

Answer (score 6):

## C, <s>104</s> 96 bytes

```c
#define a(i)s(i)|b
#define b(i)u(i)|c
#define c(i)u(i)|b
b,c,d;s(i){b=c=i;i=d;}u(i){c=b+=i;i=d;}
```

Uses the method from the link that @JulianWolf shared. Last argument must be 0.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/c-gcc#PYuxCsMwDER3f0VICUjUQ9vQyfhjLCkBDTWlSScn355YBXc4uPeOOy4yzZqnLoHiUrORa4oqfk3xX3FT5Mizl2CXQpGjBo0SdhsLR7o2cbySZsDy/mheZ@gH6QbpvUvwRBgRHgg3NLz/@mjosP5O)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/57423/discussion-on-answer-by-betseg-arbitrary-length-currying).

Answer (score 5):

## Math.JS, 38 Bytes

```
f(x)=i(x,0)
i(x,y)=x<0?y:j(z)=i(z,y+x)
```

Call it with `f(number_a)(number_b)(...)(negative_number)`

If we're allowed to specify the initial call, 12 bytes (`f(x)=i(x,0)\n`) can be dropped, and it can be called with `i(number_one,0)(number_two)(...)(negative_number)`

[Try it!](http://a-ta.co/math/f(x)%3Di(x%2C0)%0Ai(x%2Cy)%3Dx%3C0%3Fy%3Aj(z)%3Di(z%2Cy%2Bx)%0A%0Aprint(%0A%20%20%20%20f(3)(4)(5)(-1)%0A)%0A)

### Explanation

$$
\begin{align}
f(x) & = i(x, 0) \\
i(x, y) & = \begin{cases}
y, & \text{if } x < 0 \\
j(z) = i(z, y+x), & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
\end{align}
$$

As shown above, `f(x)` simply calls `i(x,0)`, then, `i(x,y)` returns the value of `y` if `x` is less than 0, or the function `j(z)=i(z,x+y)` otherwise.

Answer (score 4):

### C, <s>232</s> 206 bytes

```
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#define f(X)s(""#X)?0:g
#define g(X)u(""#X)?0:h
#define h(X)u(""#X)?0:g
g=0,h=0;s(char*s){g=h=atoi(s);return 0;}u(char*s){char*a=strlen(s)?s:"0";g=h+=atoi(a);return 0;}
```

This can probably be golfed significantly, but should serve as a proof of concept that C can be used, without any language extensions*, to solve this problem by calling without arguments rather than with a magic value.

* @hvd has noted that, while this works out of the box using gcc, some of the behavior is not defined in the C standard, meaning that this may not be portable. Use at your own risk!

Ungolfed:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define f(X) start("" #X) ? 0 : f0
#define f0(X) update("" #X) ? 0 : f1
#define f1(X) update("" #X) ? 0 : f0

long f0 = 0;
long f1 = 0;

int start(const char *s) {
    f0 = f1 = strtol(s, NULL, 10);

    return 0;
}

int update(const char *s) {
    const char *a = strlen(s) ? s : "0";
    f0 = f1 += strtol(a, NULL, 10);

    return 0;
}

int main() {
    printf("f(1)()          -> %ld\n", f(1)());
    printf("f(1)(2)(0)(3)() -> %ld\n", f(1)(2)(0)(3)());
    printf("f(1)(-2)(3)()   -> %ld\n", f(1)(-2)(3)());
    printf("f()             -> %ld\n", f());

    return 0;
}
```

Compiling and running with `gcc arbitrary-length-currying.c -o arbitrary-length-currying && ./arbitrary-length-currying` outputs (after some warnings)

```
f(1)()          -> 1
f(1)(2)(3)(0)() -> 6
f(1)(-2)(3)()   -> 2
f()             -> 0
```

Comment: "without any language extensions" -- The trick of alternating between `g` and `h` to continue a chain of macro invocations is not guaranteed to work, as it's unspecified whether the next `g` appears in the context of the expansion of the first `g`. C11 adds an example to 6.10.3.4 to spell out that it's unspecified. (IIRC, TenDRA's preprocessor is one that wouldn't expand it the way you want.) Aside from that, no version of the language supports both empty macro arguments and implicit int, so a valid C program cannot use both. :) Still, nice answer. Are you looking to golf it further?

Comment: @hvd: yeah, probably gonna come back to it in a couple of days and see if I can golf it down. You're definitely right that this is unspecified behavior, but I think the standard treatment on here is that languages are defined by their implementation, so as long as it works with gcc I'm happy.

Comment: I was just addressing the comment you included in your answer that it doesn't rely on any language extensions. Yes, even with language extensions, it's perfectly valid as an answer here, didn't mean to suggest otherwise.

Comment: Ah, that's definitely fair. You're right that I should stipulate that, while no extra flags are required, this may not be portable.

Comment: You can test for the empty string with `*s` instead of `strlen(s)`.  C strings are implicit-length, terminated by a `char` with value `0`.  Nice macro hack to allow call with/without an arg!

Answer (score 4):

## 8086 machine code, 27 bytes

```
00000000  bb 00 00 85 c0 74 13 01  d8 be 00 01 89 e7 47 47  |.....t........GG|
00000010  57 b9 1b 00 f3 a4 5b 89  47 01 c3                 |W.....[.G..|
0000001b
```

This machine code must be at address 0x100, and assumes the tiny code model (cs=ds=es=ss).  The function location can be changed without costing extra bytes, though.  Putting it at offset `0` would save a byte (`xor si,si` instead of `mov si, 0x100`)

**Required calling convention**

This assumes the caller has pre-allocated at least 27 bytes on the stack. It takes a number in `ax`, and returns a function pointer in `bx`. Calling this pointer with `ax=0` terminates the chain, and returns the sum in `bx`.
So for the first call:

```
mov bp, sp
sub sp, 28
mov ax, number_to_add
call function
; new function pointer in bx
```

Then, for each subsequent call:

```
sub sp, 28
mov ax, number_to_add
call bx
; new function pointer in bx
```

To terminate:

```
mov ax, 0
call bx
; result in bx
mov sp, bp
```

---

#### Ungolfed (commented disassembly of the machine code):

```
00000000  BB0000            mov bx,0x0      ; 0 is replaced after copying
00000003  85C0              test ax,ax
00000005  7413              jz 0x1a         ; if(ax==0) ret (with value in bx)
00000007  01D8              add ax,bx       ; arg += total
00000009  BE0001            mov si,0x100    ; address of the original: ds:0x100
0000000C  89E7              mov di,sp
0000000E  47                inc di
0000000F  47                inc di          ; dst = sp+2 = above return address
00000010  57                push di
00000011  B91B00            mov cx,0x1b
00000014  F3A4              rep movsb         ; copy the function code.
00000016  5B                pop bx            ; bx = start of copy destination
00000017  894701            mov [bx+0x1],ax   ; update total in the copied code
0000001A  C3                ret               ; with bx = function pointer
```

After calling this with non-zero AX, `bx = sp` and the buffer is filled with a modified copy of the machine code from `function`.  The 16-bit immediate in the first instruction holds the total.  (It's written by the last instruction before the `ret`.)

`push di` / `pop bx` could be replaced with `mov bx, di` (before `rep movsb`), making it simpler but no savings.

Requiring the caller to pass a pointer to the dst buffer in `di` would save 4 bytes vs. calculating it relative to `sp`.

Making the function start address the same as the function size would save a byte (`mov cx, si`).

Comment: This would be a better answer if you included disassembly of the machine-code bytes.  machine-code answers *definitely* need an ungolfed version.  e.g. use `objdump -b binary` instead of `hexdump -C`

Comment: Updated with commented disassembly.  Possible savings: require the caller to pass a dst pointer in `di` (4 bytes).  Make the function start address = size: `mov cx, si` instead of `mov cx, 0x1b`.

Answer (score 3):

## Scala, 58 chars

```
case class f(n:Int){def apply(m:Int)=f(n+m)
def apply()=n}
```

[Try it online](https://ideone.com/RgGL2q)

#### Ungolfed:

```
case class f(n:Int){
  def apply(m:Int)=f(n+m)
  def apply()=n
}
```

#### Explanation:

This code defines a `case class` called f with a constructor taking an int. Definind a case class which will generate the equals, hashcode, toString and copy methods, and a companion object with the same name to enable object creation without the `new` keyword.

This class has an overloaded apply method:
One takes another integer to add and creates a new object with the updated sum, and one without arguments to get the sum.

In Scala, any object with an apply method can be called like a method, that is `o.apply(x)` can be written as `o(x)`. This is used in the standard libary for arrays, lists, maps and the `Function1` trait implemented by anonymous functions

Answer (score 3):

## C (GCC), 83 bytes

My first C golf! There are a couple of other C solutions, but this one's a bit different. Preprocessor use is purely cosmetic. This approach was first discussed in Conor O'Brien's answer [here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/117049).

```c
#define r union r
t=0;r{int v;r(*f)();};r e;r f(a){t+=a;e.v=a?f:t;t*=a>0;return e;}
```

The terminal value is zero. The return value is a union, so to call the result, use field `f`, and to access the final value, use field `v`, e.g.

```c
f(1).f(2).f(3).f(0).v
```

[Try It Online](https://tio.run/##fY5BDsIgEEXX9hSTGhOolVC7c4JexA2hoCycGqRsmp69UmOMC@Ni3ur9/8fsLsbMniLcQ6ZjpqdHBHPVAaoahBAc53VnnScLAQbyPUEoopIYxiWWMLDKccZxwgA2n2Oaj3GrNFqRlD65Q8RYKX3MERuHQNmaXpM37Yml3nccxmL1fqDcdGcq61zTcOHYfkG7QHKROP7w2o/y32uklF/CND8B)

### Limitations

A global variable holds the running total. While this is explicitly disallowed, the submission does support repeated invocations (the total is reset in the terminal call), which seems to be the reason for the ban on global state.

A pointer to `f` is stored to the returned union through the `int` member, so this is clearly not portable. I'm not sure if this works on GCC on all platforms or just on Linux or just on x86 or just with ELF or... If anyone knows any details about this, please comment or send a message!

Answer (score 3):

## [APL (Dyalog Classic)](https://www.dyalog.com/), <s>48</s> <s>47</s> <s>46</s> <sub>44</sub> 32 bytes

```apl
∇r←(a f)x
r←⍎'(a+x)f'↓⍨-0=x
∇
0f
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNzkksLs5M/v@ob2pm/qO2CQb/H3W0FwEZGokKaZoVXCDmo94@dY1E7QrNNPVHbZMf9a7QNbCt4AKq4zJI@@@mAFShYJDGBTQBzNRwUzDUVDBA8CECRkCx/wA)

Terminates by passing in zero . Call syntax: `((0 f 1) 2) 0`

-15 bytes thanks to @ngn

Requires `⎕IO←0`

Any golfing tips are welcome!

Comment: if you can use 0 as terminator value, change `:If x<0` to `:If×x` and swap the "if" and "else" clauses

Comment: Derp. I didn't see that it said "non-positive"

Comment: do you know this trick? `r←⍎condition⊃'else' 'then'`

Comment: [32 bytes](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNzkksLs5M/v@ob2pm/qO2CQb/H3W0FwEZGokKaZoVXCDmo94@dY1E7QrNNPVHbZMf9a7QNbCt4AKq4zJI@@@mAFShYJDGBTQBzNRwUzDUVDBA8CECRkCx/wA)

Comment: Thought that said 22... >_<

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 39 bytes

```python
class f(int):__call__=lambda s,o:f(s+o)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/PzknsbhYIU0jM69E0yo@PjkxJyc@3jYnMTcpJVGhWCffKk2jWDtf839BEVCFRpqGiaaGkaaGuaaGKZhhoKnJhS6l@R8A)

Not the shortest ([by 3 bytes](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/117022/87681)), but it's different from all previous Python approaches. It works by making a callable `int` subclass. Termination call is optional, but requires a `0` argument if used.

Answer (score 2):

## Pyth, 19 bytes

```
DhdDebR?bh+dbdR$end
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/pyth#@@@SkeKSmhRkn5ShnZKUEqSSmpfyv6AoM69EIyM1MUXDWFPDVFPDTFPDLz8vVVPzPwA)

I'm impressed that Javascript beats Pyth, but then again Pyth is not quite designed to be passing functions.

Answer (score 2):

## [Dyvil](https://github.com/dyvil/dyvil), 34 bytes

```
infix int apply(i:int,j:int=0)=i+j
```

**Usage**:

```
0() // = 0
0(1)() // = 1
0(1)(2)() // = 3
```

The trailing `()` can be omitted.

**Explanation**:

Defines a juxtaposition operator that takes two ints and adds them. The parameter `j` has the default value `0` to support the call without arguments. The `0` in the examples above is not the name, but a literal.

Answer (score 2):

### C#, 62 bytes

```cs
dynamic f(int n)=>(System.Func<int,dynamic>)(m=>m<0?n:f(n+m));
```

To end the call pass in a negative number e.g.

```cs
f(1)(2)(3)(-1) == 6
```

Comment: I'd like to get it to work by passing in `null` or no parameters to end. However, all the ways I tried were a lot longer

Comment: Can you use `!m` instead of `m<0` and pass `null` or `0` as the last parameter?

Comment: @betseg No in C# only a `Boolean` can be be used as a `Boolean`... I tried with `null` but it just got longer. I wanted to use `??` which means if LHS is null do RHS, but as I need if LHS is not null do this else do RHS I couldn't.

Answer (score 2):

### Perl 5, 36 bytes

```
sub f{my$n=pop;sub{@_?f($n+pop):$n}}
```

---

```
say f(1)->(); # 1
say f(1)->(2)->(3)->(); # 6
```

Comment: What about this requires `-M5.016`? It seems like you should be able to drop `-M5.016` and then also drop `my` and save a couple bytes. If it's just `say`, you can use the flag `-E` instead, which doesn't activate `use strict`, so you can still drop the `my`.

Comment: @Chris you're right, it doesn't need 5.16, my initial revision did (using `__SUB__`) but I changed that before submit and didn't remove the bit about 5.16. I'll remove that. I don't think dropping `my` would be correct though.

Comment: (and no, I'm not counting `say` as part of the code, it's only for illustrative purposes)

Comment: If you remove `my` without `use strict`, `$n` is implicitly a global variable. It's bad form in proper perl scripts, but it's pretty common in one-liners, and it seems to work here.

Answer (score 2):

## [Brain-Flak](https://github.com/Flakheads/BrainHack), 6 bytes

Actually I just noticed that since the [ToS is a valid return format](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8507/48198) popping the *0* is not really needed which saves 2 bytes:

```
({{}})
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKzMzLSEzO/v9fo7q6tlbz////xkb/dQ2N/hsZ/jf8bwAA)

### Original submission(s), 8 bytes

Uses `0` as the special value:

```
({{}}{})
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKzMzLSEzO/v9fo7q6tra6VvP////GRv91DY3@Gxn@N/xvAAA)

#### Explanation

Given the arguments *a<sub>1</sub>*, *a<sub>2</sub>*, … , *a<sub>n</sub>*, *0* the stack initially looks like this:

*a<sub>n</sub>*

*⋮*

*a<sub>2</sub>*

*a<sub>1</sub>*

*0*

The code then goes on, pops every *a<sub>i</sub>*, accumulates them, pops the *0* adds them and pushes the result:

```
(      )  -- push the following value:
 {  }     --   while ToS ≠ 0 (sums the runs):
  {}      --     pop 1 element
     {}   --   pop the remaining 0 & add it
```

---

#### Alternative solutions, 8 bytes

Instead of popping the *0* and adding it to the sum, we can also swap stacks since the right one is initially empty:

```
({{}}<>)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKzMzLSEzO/v9fo7q6ttbGTvP////GRv91DY3@Gxn@N/xvAAA)

Using the `-r` flag the *0* is on the top of the stack, so we could pop it first:

```
({}{{}})
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKzMzTTctJzP7/X6O6trq6tlbz/39jIwVdQyMFI0MFQwWD/7pFAA)

```
{}({{}})
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKzMzTTctJzP7/v7pWo7q6tlbz/39jIwVdQyMFI0MFQwWD/7pFAA)

Comment: Oh my goodness... Great one!

Answer (score 2):

## Java 8, 111 bytes

A lambda from `int` to a function. Calls are terminated by passing zero.

```java
i->new java.util.function.Function<Long,Object>(){int t=i;public Object apply(Long x){t+=x;return x<1?t:this;}}
```

[Try It Online](https://tio.run/##nVA7T8MwEJ6dX3GjLVoLJGAgTRALEhKIoSNicBM3XHCdyL6UVFF@e0iIKyQGXtPd95LuvlLt1bKqtS3z16FuNgYzyIzyHh4UWugiFkhPisaxRasMlGNKNoRGbhubEVZW3oZldWdJF9otvjXdV7ZYwOOm1BmlKWSNc6jzmzyHZMBlavXbz/GQ5qJDS0AJxuHUWQBV1@bAJyu0oqOTpI2dpsZZaFdn13RFL@jjvh9YHH39cl9hDruxAL4mh7Z4egblCi@mPtj64EnvZNWQrEeRjOUjyzj/9cNi8v898I8E@2xWzn2cB0UEfGFm4ogvZ3yEpx9QxBHroz4a3gE)

### Ungolfed

```java
i ->
    new java.util.function.Function<Long, Object>() {
        int t = i;
        public Object apply(Long x) {
            t =+ x;
            return x < 1 ? t : this;
        }
    }
```

Due to an interesting interplay between byte counts of primitive and object integer types, intermediate functions take a `Long` as a parameter, but the total is stored in and returned as an `int`.

### Limitations

The returned function is mutated when called, so, for instance, it's not possible to obtain two integer results without two calls of the lambda. However, the functions returned by separate calls to the lambda are fully independent, so it seems the challenge requirements are met.

Liberal casting is required when constructing expressions that use the lambda. See the TIO for a usage example.

Comment: It's actually a lambda from int to an Object.

Comment: Well you can cast it that way, but the actual return type isn't `Object`.

Answer (score 2):

## [Rust](https://www.rust-lang.org/), 134 bytes

```rust
|x|{fn b(a:i32,n:i32)->Box<dyn std::any::Any>{if n>0{Box::new(Box::new(move|x|b(a+n,x))as Box<dyn Fn(_)->_>)}else{Box::new(a)}}b(0,x)}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##nY7LrsIwDET3@YpcVrZuQTzExoVIsOA3UKCpVKm4qElpq5BvL2HBo1s2lmXPnJm6sW7IWV50wYC@NE7mciuHe3f38XwCTcVqmfBz4lTtq26T9Syty4g090Q77pUvcslq7uOXiE0L7@VS3UxERcw/Jx2itvKFODAcI/GoMJjSmo9ZYwgnmEd5GFLRWDNOS8W1LtiV/AcTHyYJ5LDCWVa1fNbWEW2@Asaln1WVApw13Nb6Coiw/tEJ08XIGeUjcCqCEMMD)

In your face, strict type system! Terminates if the input is negative. You do have to downcast the result after every call though (see tio). I took a similar approach to the Math.js solution.

ungolfed:

```rust
|x| {
        fn b(a: i32, n: i32) -> Box<dyn std::any::Any> {
            if n > 0 { 
                Box::new(Box::new(move |x| b(a + n, x)) as Box<dyn Fn(_) -> _>)
            } else {
                Box::new(a)
            }
        }
        b(0, x)
    }
```

Rust's strong type system makes this almost impossible. Fortunately, trait objects come to the rescue. Trait objects erase the type and all associated data except for the trait's implementation. In this instance, I use the `Any` trait, which allows downcasting back into a concrete type. There are some wrinkles because you can't explicitly name the type of closures, so I have to cast the closure into a `Fn` trait object and then recast it into an an `Any` before use.

Answer (score 2):

### PHP7.4 (45 chars)

The superglobal function **[$_ENV](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.environment.php)** will return an adder function continuously.
After the operations, when no argument is provided **$_ENV** will return the result.
The function **$_ENV** is not designed to accept a negative value or no input at all.

```php
$_ENV=fn($a)=>fn($b=-1)=>~$b?$_ENV($a+$b):$a;
```

Usage :

```php
var_dump($_ENV(1)() == 1);                 // bool(true)
var_dump($_ENV(4)(2)(7)() == 13);          // bool(true)
var_dump($_ENV(4)(2)(7)(5)(2)() == 20);    // bool(true)
```

**Info**: Overriding a [superglobal](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.superglobals.php) like *$_ENV* variable isn't recommended.

Answer (score 2):

## [Aussie++](https://github.com/zackradisic/aussieplusplus/), <s>98</s> 96 bytes

-2 because I remembered the angle brackets aren't necessary for a single-statement `YA RECKON` body.

```
THE HARD YAKKA FOR f IS(x)<THE HARD YAKKA FOR g IS(y)<YA RECKON y ?BAIL f(x +y);BAIL x;>BAIL g;>
```

Tested in commit 9522366. For the final call, give it `BUGGER ALL` or `YEAH, NAH!` instead of a number.

The general structure is something like

```js
function f(x) {
    function g(y) {
        if (y) return f(x + y);
        return x;
    }
    return g;
}
```

Since Aussie++ doesn't have function expressions or anonymous functions yet, it is necessary to put the function declaration and return as separate statements.

Answer (score 1):

## C#, <strike>91</strike> 58 bytes

```
dynamic f(int x)=>(Func<int, dynamic>)(y=>y<1?x:f(x + y));
```

Comment: You can get rid of some spaces and the `public `.

Answer (score 1):

### [Julia](https://julialang.org/) v0.5+, 52 bytes

```
type F n end
F()=0
(f::F)()=f.n
(f::F)(x)=(f.n+=x;f)
```

Call as `F`. This could probably be made a lot shorter by adopting a less OO method, but I always like getting the chance to use this idiom.

If it can be assumed that "at least one call will be made before the termination call", the second line can be removed to save 6 bytes.

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 6](http://perl6.org/), 31 bytes

```
sub f(\n){->$m?{$m??f n+$m!!n}}
```

Answer (score 1):

## PHP, 44 Bytes

An Idea from [@user63956](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/63956/user63956)

Termination call `0`

```
function f($i){return[$_GET[0]+=$i][$i]?:f;}
```

[Online Version](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/03419ad8be41d166de374cc7dc144274fd5a1cf0)

Termination call with `NULL` need a càst `[$i]` to `[+$i]`

## PHP, 47 Bytes

```
function f($i){global$s;return$i?f.!$s+=$i:$s;}
```

[Online Version](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/1d2b18bcc5c0cd2c670ad83c8fb7185d30244b25)

## PHP, 52 Bytes

Termination call `NULL` or any other value that is false in PHP

```
function f($i){global$s;$i?$s+=$i:print$s;return f;}
```

if the program must terminate after the Output replace `print$s` with `die("$s")` + 2 Bytes

[Online Version](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/6595b125390e7d6dfc8795d6eb8e5141bc131bcc)

Comment: I think the function should return (not print) `$s`. so you could do something like `return$i?f:$s` at the end

Comment: @ConorO'Brien I am not sure but if your Thinking is right it could save 5 Bytes Thank You

Comment: A few bytes can be saved with superglobal variables: `function f($i){return[$_GET[0]+=$i][$i]?:f;}`.

Comment: @user63956 a very nice idea

Answer (score 1):

### [Python](https://www.python.org/]), 61 bytes

```
f=lambda n="":0if n==""else lambda m="":n if m==""else f(n+m)
```

Much longer than the other Python version, but uses the no-argument syntax rather than a magic number. Can probably be improved upon.

If it can be assumed that "at least one call will be made before the termination call", this can be reduced to **44 bytes**:

```
f=lambda n:lambda m="":n if m==""else f(n+m)
```

Comment: You can use 0 as default value and gain a bunch of bytes rearranging things: `f=lambda n=0:n and(lambda m=0:m and f(n+m)or n)or n`

Answer (score 1):

## [Julia 0.5](http://julialang.org/), 18 bytes

```julia
!n=k->k>0?!(n+k):n
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/julia5#@6@YZ5uta5dtZ2CvqJGnna1plfc/N7FAo6AoM68kJ08nmotTQ1FTw1BTw0ATwjTR1DDS1DDHImAKZgCFYzX/AwA)

Answer (score 1):

### R, <s>54</s> 52 bytes

```
f=function(x){g=function(y='')'if'(y>'',f(x+y),x);g}
```

*Saved 2 bytes thanks to MickyT!*

Similar to one of the python answers. Ungolfed:

```
f=function(x){
  g=function(y=''){
    if(y>''){
      f(y+x)
      }
      else{x}
  }
  g
}
```

Runs as

```
> f(1)(2)(4)()
[1] 7
```

Comment: Nice work. You can get rid of the internal braces around the if clause. `f=function(x){g=function(y='')'if'(y>'',f(x+y),x);g}`

Comment: I’m a bit puzzled why your “ungolfed” version has `return`. `return` in R isn’t the same as in other languages, it performs a premature abort. Not using `return` is idiomatic. On the other hand your ungolfed version still has the golfed `if`.

Comment: @KonradRudolph The golfed `if` was laziness, but the `return` is just for readability - it gives the same result with or without `return`.

Comment: @BLT Hm. I feel strongly that gratuitous in R `return` *decreases* readability because it signals the wrong thing (premature exit) and is an instance of [cargo cult programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cargo_cult_programming).

Comment: Cool, I learned something new again. That's one reason I keep coming back. Thanks @KonradRudolph, also this Stack Overflow question is interesting: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11738823/explicitly-calling-return-in-a-function-or-not

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 63 bytes

```python
f=lambda n,l=[]:n and(l.append(n)or f)or sum(l)*(l.clear()or 1)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/python3#@59mm5OYm5SSqJCnk2MbHWuVp5CYl6KRo5dYUJAKZORp5hcppIGI4tJcjRxNLaBUck5qYpEGSMxQ839BUWZeiUaahqGmhommhqmmhoGmJhdM0BgsCBT5DwA)

---

Terminates with 0

Answer (score 1):

## [C++ (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <s>95</s> 91 bytes

```cpp
struct f{int s;f(int t):s(t){}int operator()(){return s;}f operator()(int t){return s+t;}};
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/cpp-gcc#dY7BCsIwDIbve4qwISQogqII1nnzCdzRy1hbLGg32gyE0mef6wbqxVPy/18@yODZ9Q2DDsYyeKExTaajR6YQU2g75WpuHRJScIp7Z8fDqH/BLH3okkWMYiiMbR69VHDyLE27vp@zQiptrILqcq1QvTpH0LnR1likBDmUJSzkzeYrmHD2rI1FykIGs6RxMz5C4pt3hFvCw792Py2JxeEN)

Answer (score 1):

## Python, 69 bytes

```
def f(a=0,s=[]):
    if a:
        return lambda b=0:f(b,s+[a])
    return sum(s)
```

Comment: I'm assuming this is python? You should state the language used in your answer.

Comment: Can you try to golf your answer more? As it stands, it's not very well golfed.

Answer (score 1):

## R, 40 bytes

```r
f=function(x)function(y)`if`(y,f(x+y),x)
```

0 acts as the stop value here. For two more bytes, we can omit it.

The problem is that R lacks a concise built-in lambda. But [if we add one](https://github.com/klmr/functional/#a-concise-lambda-syntax), we can get the code to **26 bytes**:

```r
f=x->(y->`if`(y,f(x+y),x))
```

(Yes, that’s valid R. It just needs an import.)

Answer (score 1):

**PowerShell, 86 bytes**

```
$f={$n=$args[0];$f=(gv f).value;{if($args){&$f($args[0]+$n)}else{$n}}.getnewclosure()}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/powershell#@6@SZlutkmerkliUXhxtEGsN5GuklymkaeqVJeaUplpXZ6ZpgCU1q9VUoEygOm2VPM3a1JziVKDm2lq99NSSvNTy5Jz84tKiVA3N2v9qGnCokqZgommkaa5pCiT/f83L101OTM5IBQA)

**Test code:**

```
&(&(&(&(&(&$f 4)2)7)5)2)
```

**Output:** 20

Comment: Very nice. Welcome to PPCG! You can save a byte by doing `$n="$args"` instead of `$n=$args[0]`. It won't work on the other `$args[0]`, though, because then you'll get string concatenation rather than addition.

Answer (score 1):

## Octave, 39 bytes

```matlab
function r=f(n)r=@(m)merge(m,f(m+n),n);
```

*Argument of the termination call is 0.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/octave#@59Wmpdckpmfp1Bkm6aRp1lk66CRq5mbWpSeqpGrk6aRq52nqZOnaf0/NS8FppQrTcNIU8NQU8NUU8NAk@s/AA)

*`endfunction` required to add some other codes.

Answer (score 1):

## Lua, 89 bytes

```
function f(...)n,p=...p=p or 0 return n and loadstring("return f(...,"..n+p..")")or p end
```

Well it's not exactly the shortest I see (Lua never is), but it was an interesting challenge. Had a lot of attempted arithmetic on a function and attempted to call a number along the way before the aha moment.

As a slight bonus though, it does work with non-positive numbers since nil and false are the only false values in Lua. In many golfing challenges, 0 ~= false is a drawback but not here!

Answer (score 1):

## k, 22 bytes

Call with a null value to terminate

```
{$[^y;+/x;.z.s[y,x]@]}
```

Example:

```
k)f:{$[^y;+/x;.z.s[y,x]@]}
k)g:f[3]
k)h:g[4]
k)h[0N] //0N is null integer in k
7
```

Answer (score 1):

### Clojure, 29 bytes

```
(defn f[n]#(if %(f(+ n %))n))
```

Example:

```
(for [f (->> [3 2 1 4 10] (reductions (fn [f val] (f val)) f) rest)]
  (f nil))
(3 5 6 10 20)
```

Answer (score 1):

**C#, 53 bytes**

```
Func<int,dynamic>f(int i)=>m=>m<0?(dynamic)i:f(m+i);
```

Any negative number can act as the stop value

```
int j = f(5)(3)(4)(-1); // j = 12

int j = f(-1); // Compile Error, must be 2 or more calls
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Attache](https://github.com/ConorOBrien-Foxx/Attache), 20 bytes

```
{If[_,$&Sum[__],_2]}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SywpSUzOSP2fZmX7v9ozLTpeR0UtuDQ3Oj4@VifeKLb2f0BRZl5JdFq0YWy0QWwsF4xrEhttFBttjkPQFMwASv0HAA)

### Explanation

```
{If[_,$&Sum[__],_2]}
{                  }    lambda, taking parameters stored in `__`
 If[_,            ]     If the first parameter `_` is truthy (nonzero):
      $                    return this function
       &                   bonded with
        Sum[__]            the current running sum
               ,        otherwise:
                _2         return the sum
```

Since `(f&n)[x]` is equivalent to `f[x, n]`, this will continue returning itself with the updated sum until `n = 0`.

If you want computation to occur after the final `0`, then one could do this for 28 bytes:

```
{If[_,Fold[`&,$'__],Sum!__]}
```

This is much the same thing, except we use `` Fold[`&,$'__] `` to bond `$` with each individual argument.

Answer (score 1):

## [Nim](http://nim-lang.org/), 135 bytes

```
import sugar
type X=object
 case t:int8
 of 0:i:int
 else:f:int->X
func s(x:int):int->X=(y:int)=>(if y<0:X(t:0,i:x)else:X(t:1,f:s x+y))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LcxBCoMwEAXQfU4xywxV0dLSMqjnyNaGpJ1SjZgIyenTRrr5/Dcwf@E5Z55XtwXw@3PaREirATW4x9voIEBP3kAgXsJdgLPQEhcIMB9vyJZej0rYfdHgZSzG/3GQ6eAwSraQ@paUDNRWTBGP78KusuQhnhJiNvrlfiMXlGdsrLyVuJY4WHfYcP4C)

Like the JavaScript answer, but with type safety.

Answer (score 1):

### Google Sheets, 39

Based on the explanation [here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/117060/)

Named functions:

| name | args | body |
| --- | --- | --- |
| F | a | `G(0,a)` |
| G | a, b | `IF(b>0,LAMBDA(c,G(a+b,c)),a)` |

Score: 34 (body text) + 2 (names) + 3 (args) = 39

#### Example

Termination call arg is any non-positive number:

```
=F(2)(4)(0)
```

gives 6.

Answer (score 0):

## [Go](https://go.dev), 87 bytes

```go
func f(x int)func(int)any{g:=func(y int)any{if y<1{return x+y}
return f(x+y)}
return g}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m70oPX_B7oLE5OzE9FSF3MTMPK7M3IL8ohIFPQWltNwSpaWlJWm6FjfD00rzkhXSNCoUMvNKNEEcDRAjMa-yOt3KFsyvVICJZKYpVNoYVhellpQW5SlUaFfWckHZQAO0KzXh3PRaqPHPwcaDrNfQVKjmCigCGpWTp5GmYaypYaKpp4FsoaaGgaaCra2CuSaSOkOYqCGyqImmhhGGbnMc5hkak6HVFEMEUxfEeCMDTS6odxcsgNAA)

Stopping value is 0.

This works because the `any` in Go represents all types, at the expense of every call after the 2nd needing to be cast with `.(func(int)any)`, like `f(3)(4).(func(int)any)(0)`.